# Should I delete my question, reword and post anew?

Tags: discussion, edits, specific-question

I recently asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38576692/boxplot-placed-on-time-axis) and stated on the comments that a procedure solved the problem, which turned out not to be true (my mistake, I only realized later). I specifically asked the poster to post the comment as answer, which she/he did. Now, I would like to edit the question to make it more understandable, but feel bad about my error. The post does not answer the original question, while still giving some advice.

What feels better to me now is to cut the back-and-forth comments, accept the (only) answer and delete the question altogether (before it gets some more views or posts). Then I could take some time to make more tests and, eventually, post another, better, one. I feel that question/answer, as it is now, would not be helpful in the future.

Is there any advice on this kind of situation?

Comment: You may make minor corrections to the question, but see to that you don't change the question entirely. And add the correct answer there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't delete the question (because it has an upvoted answer), and generally, if you edit your question, you should not invalidate existing answers (this is typical 'help vampire' behaviour). But in this (rare) case, the answer isn't even valid to begin with.

I think the current question is quite understandable right now, so just leave it alone; somebody else with a similar question might hit the page via Google, and for him/her the proposed answer might just work. We're here not (only) to help you, but to build a compendium of Q&As for future visitors (as well).<sup>*</sup> You already left a comment indicating the answer doesn't work for you – perfect. Good luck with your research and we'll wait for your new question. You might want to link your original question to your new question, if it helps giving context, and the new answer might make sense for the original question as well.

<sup>*</sup>: remove the parentheses and/or the words inside the parentheses depending on your viewpoint.

Comment: I upvoted the answer myself, since it pointed out a line of code that makes a difference (and gave thus an insight). It does not answer the question itself, though.

Comment: ... and explaining how your new question isn't a dupe of your old question will help inhibit the dupe hammer trigger reflex of at least some of your readers.